# Open pinned tab from a Teams App while joining a Meeting

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I have a Teams App which supports Meeting. In a Online meeting, you can select my Teams App and pin a result as a tab.

Using graph api, I am getting the join web url. but I want to extend the Join web url with Deeplink of Pinned tab. So when user click on Join meeting - User joins the meeting and the pinned tab gets open in Side panel on Meeting. As you see in the image, Instead of meeting notes, my app pinned Tab gets open as soon as you join using that URL.

Does anyone know how this deeplink will look. I will be happy to hear.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use Deep link to meeting side panel:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-link-workflow?tabs=teamsjs-v2#deep-link-to-meeting-side-panel

Sample link: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/tab-deeplink

You can also try with Link to a tab app added to a meeting or group chat:

Reference doc link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-link-application?tabs=teamsjs-v2#configure-deep-link-to-browse-within-your-app-manually

Comment: I tried all these, but nothing worked. It is always landing either to Teams Meeting chat or pinned entity. I want user to be presented a join screen, and when user join in team side panel, the pinned entity from my app. The url must be then starts with https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/.................. and then some app and entity details.

Comment: If you want the deep link to open directly in your app rather than the Teams meeting side panel, you can add openInMeeting=false to the deep link:

https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/<appId>/<entityId>?webUrl=<entityWebUrl>&label=<entityLabel>&context=<context>&openInMeeting=false